# Building GTK3 with meson and MSYS2 on Windows fails

Tags: windows, gtk, msys2, meson-build

Trying to build stable release 3.24.21 of GTK3 from the git sources using MSYS2 on Windows following [these instructions](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/gtk-building.html). I've successfully built this version earlier from the tar.xz sources and MSYS2 `configure/make` so I know I have all the required dependencies.

After cloning the gtk repo, I checkout the desired version. Then I run `meson` as described in the instructions.

```
git checkout -b issue1234 3.24.21
meson setup --prefix /opt/gtk3 _build
```

For some reason, `meson` fails to find either `pkg-config` or `cmake`, both of which exist in the PATH. It also believes it needs to build the latest version of `glib2` although a sufficient version exists. When `meson` tries to build `glib2`, it bombs out with:

```
subprojects/glib/meson.build:1680:2: ERROR: Entry _WIN32_WINNT not in configuration data.
```

`_WIN32_WINNT` was presumably set in the following `glib/meson.build` block (it's the only place in the file where it's set):

```
# Windows SDK requirements and checks
if host_system == 'windows'
  # Check whether we're building for UWP apps
  code = '''
  #include <windows.h>
  #if !(WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP) && !WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP))
  #error "Not building for UWP"
  #endif'''
  if cc.compiles(code, name : 'building for UWP')
    glib_conf.set('G_WINAPI_ONLY_APP', true)
    # We require Windows 10+ on WinRT
    glib_conf.set('_WIN32_WINNT', '0x0A00')
  else
    # We require Windows 7+ on Win32
    **glib_conf.set('_WIN32_WINNT', '0x0601')**
  endif
endif
```

And the last line of this block in `glib/meson.build` is where it bombs:

```
if has_syspoll and has_systypes
  poll_includes = '''
      #include<sys/poll.h>
      #include<sys/types.h>'''
elif has_winsock2
  poll_includes = '''
      #define _WIN32_WINNT @0@
      #include <winsock2.h>'''.format(glib_conf.get('_WIN32_WINNT'))
```

Any ideas about what's going on? Why aren't `pkg-config/cmake` found? Why the need to build `glib2`? And why the build failure?